# Configuring Skype for Business delegates using UCMA

Tags: delegates, skype-for-business, ucma

I have been struggling to programatically add a delegate to a user (boss/admin scenario).

After running my test code in the boss sfb client the admin appears as a delegate however, in the admin's sfb client the boss does not appear under the section "people I manage calls for". I verified in the rtc frontend database that  the delegation is configured, however the admin subscription record does not list the boss. Below is the code I used to achieve this.

Any ideas why the admin sfb client is not being notified of the new delegation?

Thanks,

Simon

1) add delegate-management

```
public void SendAddDelegate()
{
    string body = string.Format($"<setDelegates xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2007/09/sip/delegate-management\" version=\"1\"><delegate uri=\"sip:admin@example.com\" action=\"add\"/></setDelegates>");
    byte[] encBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    RealTimeAddress rta = new RealTimeAddress("sip:boss@example.com");
    System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("application/msrtc-setdelegate+xml")
endpoint.InnerEndpoint.BeginSendMessage(MessageType.Service, rta, contentType, encBody, SendAddDelegateManagementMessageComplete, null);
}

private void SendAddDelegateManagementMessageComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        SipResponseData srd = endpoint.InnerEndpoint.EndSendMessage(result);
        logger.Debug($"srd.ResponseCode - {srd.ResponseCode}");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logger.Error("Exception SendMessageComplete with message - {0}", exc.Message);
    }
}
```

2) Publish presence

```
public void PublishRoutingCategory(string delegateUri)
{
    //routes not created here for sample brevity
    routes.DelegateRingEnabled = true;
    routes.Delegates.Add(delegateUri);
    routes.SimultaneousRingEnabled = true;
    routes.SimultaneousRing.Add(delegateUri);
    routes.SkipPrimaryEnabled = true;
    routes.ForwardAudioAppInvitesEnabled = true;
    try                
    {                    
        userEndpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.BeginPublishPresence(new PresenceCategory[] { routes }, PublishComplete, null);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logger.Error("Unknown error - {0}", exc.Message);
    }
}

private void PublishComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        endpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.EndPublishPresence(result);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logger.Error("Error Publish Complete- {0}", exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is voice policy enabled in your environment (I know from experience that this might not be set up in development environments for example)  us get-csvoicePolicy to check.

Comment: Thanks Paul, voicepolicy is configured for all users.  Also, when configuring delegates using the SfB client works correctly, I am only seeing this issue when I work with UCMA.

Comment: I have seen SfB being particular about including the schema in the sip address, for example using sip:admin@example rather than the shorter version in your example

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo made while trying to reduce my code down to its minimum.  Thanks for pointing that out, I have now corrected the mistake.